# ASP.NET: how to make onClientClick finish work before postback?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, onclick, onclientclick

I have such a control:

```
<asp:Button ID="save_all_filt" runat="server" Text="All data for filtered subjects"
        OnClientClick="  a= saveAllFilt(); return true; "   onclick="save_all_filt_Click" />
```

saveAllFilt contains a JQuery ajax call. So what I see in log, I have simultaneous start of postback and saveAllFilt. Postback however "delays" and does nothing before Ajax call in saveAllFilt fninshes.

I wonder if there is a way to do like this:
1. onClientClick, system goes into saveAllFilt JS function and somehow waits(!) till Ajax function finishes in this or that way.
2. Only when it is finished, a real postback starts to happen.

I do realise that JQuery ajax call is event-driven and asynchronous. Just would like to block these postback actions till it finishes (AJAX call prepares data for retrieval that happens via server postback.)

Comment: is there a reason your code-behind cant do what the ajax call is doing? it would be better to have one trip to the server instead of two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the [`async` property](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) of the jQuery AJAX config object to `false`:

```
$.ajax({
    /* ... */
    async : false
    /* ... */
})
```

Comment: This was my solution for a 3 hour head banging problem... None of my OnClientClick javascript ajax calls were working on Firefox but work on Chrome... Kudos!!