# ASP.net OnClientClick has an async call - how to proceed with server-side OnClick only when that async call is complete and successful?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have

```
<asp:Button ID="Submit_BT" runat="server" OnClientClick="return clientClick();" OnClick="Submit_BT_Click" />
```

And then in JS:

```
function clientClick(){
     // using jQuery
     $.get(..., function(result){
         // Perform some processing on result
         // Proceed with the server-side postback
     },
     function(error){
         // Don't proceed with server-side postback
     });

     return true; // ?---
}
```

I want the $.get to successfully complete before postback, but I think postback will never happen, or will always happen. Can I simply say `return $.get(...)`; How to do this?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13310883/asp-net-how-to-make-onclientclick-finish-work-before-postback) is similar, and the solution is to set `async: false`, which partially answers my question. When the call completes, it could be either successful or erroneous. Only when the call is successful do I want to proceed with the server-side click. How do I "return true or false" from inside the `$.get()`'s handlers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always return `false` in your JS function to assure that it won't postback on click.

And do manual postback in succesful async callback:

```
$.get(..., function(result){

   // Perform some processing on result

   __doPostBack('Submit_BT', '')

}
```